# Mock Laravel Model in phpunit test

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I am persuing unit test and here i don't want to use the database. And i am doing mocking of each and everything. But i am unable to mock Models. If i try to mock the model with override then it gives me this error: **class already exists**. And if i tried without overide then the mocking is not working. I also found a trait For it named laravel query factory, which helps me to give a dummy query builder. But i am facing one issue in it. When i use count funtion on model then it gives me following error:
**ErrorException: Undefined index: aggregate**

Meanwhile i am not able to mock in any way, anyone please help me to do the same

Here is the model Query which i want to mock:
MyModel::where('column_name', 12)->count();

Comment: You must have a testing database (you can even use `SQLite`), because if you try to mock everything, you can be overriding some event-driven stuff, you must use a database... Read this part of the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database-testing) and [this one about `SQLite`](https://medium.com/swlh/laravel-5-8-testing-with-sqlite-899d0fdd3494)

Comment: Yes I agree too, you should use testing database. You will only do mocking if you really need to test it on the separate test case, for example like sending email with Maillable, queuing your job, etc. Anyway we can use refresh database as well so your testing db will always be new